# Remove All non numeric row in dbgrid

Tags: delphi

i want remove all non numeric row in dbgrid

for example my dbgrid row's is:

```
row1= 127.0.0.1:900
row2= 103.43.122.40:8000
row3= 122.12.75.4:3128
row4= netfire.se98.ar:3000
row5= po-ryd.449.br:3128
row6= 93.5.32.150:6540
```

Now, remove all non numeric row in dbgrid.

Answer (score 6):

A `DbGrid` is backed by a `TDataSet` descendant. That `TDataSet` descendant has a `Filtered` property and an `OnFilterRecord` that can be used to filter records.

Here's a sample `OnFilterRecord` implementation that rejects any record that's made up of characters that are not numbers, not `'.'` or `':'`. Please note I'm not using an char-in-set test so the code is perfectly compatible with both Unicode Delphi and non-Unicode Delphi.

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
var Value: string;
    i: Integer;
    C: Char;
begin
  Value := DataSet['IP']; // Replace "IP" with your field's name
  for i:=1 to Length(Value) do
  begin
    C := Value[i];
    if not(C in ['.', ':', '0'..'9']) then // Detect bad characters
    begin
      Accept := False; // This record will NOT be shown.
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Accept := True; // No bad characters were found, show the record.
end;
```

After you assign this `OnFilterRecord` handler, don't forget to set `Filtered := True`.